# lsp plugin config file will load but not modify current buffer until sourced

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

For my Neovim setup I have a config folder under the `lua` folder that contains all of my plugin configs (lsp, tabline, telescope, etc.) as well as a print statement displaying what plugins were loaded successfully via the following which is invoked in `/zfg/init.lua`:

```lua
local plugins = {
    'pear',
    'harpoon',
    'lsp-zero',
    'treesitter',
    'undotree',
    'colors',
    'lualine',
    'snip',
    'tabline',
    'telescope',
    'tmux'
}

local imports = "Loaded: "

for i,plug in pairs(plugins) do
    _ = i
    if not pcall(require, 'zfg.config.'..plug) then
        print('Failed to load '..plug)
    else
        imports = imports.." "..plug
    end
end

print(imports)
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
nvim/
| -- init.lua
| - lua/zfg/
|    | - config/
|    |    |-- pear.lua
|    |    |-- colors.lua
|    |    |-- harpoon.lua
|    |    |-- lsp-zero.lua
|    |    |-- lualine.lua
|    |    |-- snip.lua
|    |    |-- tabline.lua
|    |    |-- telescope.lua
|    |    |-- treesitter.lua
|    |    |-- undotree.lua
|    |-- init.lua
|-- init.lua
```

I can then check this message in `:mes` to verify that most all the `require` calls worked (or at least I think that's how that works) in addition to using the other plugins.

The main issue is that other plugins will modify my buffer as expected: I can invoke snippets, the `pears.nvim` will expand on enter and use the pairs correctly, and most everything else will work as far as I've been able to tell. The issue appears to only be `lsp-zero` in that none of my setup seems to take (no bordered window boxes with suggestions, autocompletion, or mappings).

I have added an additional source command to the `/nvim/zfg/init.lua` file in an attempt to force the file to be sourced but this also failed:

```lua
local src = ":so ~/.config/nvim/lua/zfg/config/lsp-zero.lua"

vim.api.nvim_command(src)
```

It will work correctly when I source `nvim/zfg/init.lua` manually after starting up neovim but it will not work on startup despite seeing the log messages making it look like the lsp-zero.lua file was loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by changing my structure around slightly. I used the following directory configuration:

```
nvim/
|-- init.lua
| - lua/zfg/
|    | - config/
|    |    |-- pear.lua
|    |    |-- colors.lua
|    |    |-- harpoon.lua
|    |    |-- lualine.lua
|    |    |-- snip.lua
|    |    |-- tabline.lua
|    |    |-- telescope.lua
|    |    |-- treesitter.lua
|    |    |-- undotree.lua
|    |-- init.lua
| - after/plugin
|    |-- lsp-zero.lua
```

As far as I can tell this fixes the issue by loading the completion engine and LSP functionalities after everything under the `lua` directory and the plugins are loaded (if I'm understanding Neovim configuration correctly).